# Closing a DIV on an ASP.NET page with a Master page using a button in the div, where JQuery was used to show the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this DIV on my page (which has a Master page)

```
<div id="whatsNew" runat="server" style="position:absolute;left:-500px;top:500px;background-color:aliceblue;">
    <button id="closeWhatsNew" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="closeWhatsNewDiv();" type="button">Close</button>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblWhatsNew" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</div>
```

I show this div on the page with:

```
   slideshowHandle = setInterval(showWhatsNew, 5);
    function showWhatsNew() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var horizOffset = (((windowWidth - 500) / 2) + 50 + "px") ;
        $('#<%= whatsNew.ClientID %>').animate({ left: horizOffset  }, 2000);
    }
```

I used setInterval because I thought it would delay the display of the div, but ignore this. The div shows on the page, and that's fine.

What's not fine is that the button in the div is not making the div go away. Here's what I have right now that does not work:

```
function closeWhatsNewDiv() {

    try {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var horizOffset = (((windowWidth - 500) / 2) + 50 + "px") ;
        $('#<%= whatsNew.ClientID %>').animate({ left: horizOffset * -1  }, 2000);
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    } 
}
```

I know this function runs when the button is clicked because I put an alert() in the function. And, there's no exception.

I don't really care how the div 'goes away'. It would be nice to reverse the animation, but I'd settle for just hiding the div.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the page is a Web Forms ASPX page.

Comment: Your setInterval is attempting to execute every 5 milliseconds...

Comment: Looks like it just keeps showing what's new repeatedly. Even if you close it, it just pops right back up.

Comment: Why are you using setInterval instead of setTimeout?

Comment: .hide(): https://api.jquery.com/hide/   And remove the setInterval looping as other have said.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Comment: Now, how do I mark this as answered?